# Utterance triggers None intent instead of intent it has been added to

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have created an intent called "Ask 4 clear" with 15 utterances, but one of them is highlighted with red color and triggers None intent instead of one it was added to.

[screenshot](https://prntscr.com/n3aq56)

Test of this utterance gives None intent [screenshot](https://prntscr.com/n3arsh)
and reassigning to correct intent gives no result [screenshot](https://prntscr.com/n3asp7)

Having the same problem with other intents, eg [screenshot](https://prntscr.com/n3avhr)

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you retrain your model after adding these utterances?

Comment: Did retraining your model resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, I've retrained model and published it, but it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "Ask4Clear" is not a real English word, LUIS is not able to process the query correctly. One way to resolve this issue is to add more utterances to the intent that include "Ask4Clear". I would also recommend creating a Phrase List to add words to the dictionary that LUIS pulls from. For more details on how to configure a [Phrase List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-add-features), please refer to the LUIS Documentation.

Comment: I didn't know about Phrase List on Luis, Thank you)